# How to Capture screenshot on Emulator/Real device using extended report

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium-ios, appium-android

I am trying to capture screenshot on the IOS and Android emulators on Test failure but my driver returns Null. When i run the code on Chrome on my computer it runs fine and takes the screenshot on failure, the problem is when it runs on emulators. see the code below to take screenshots where the driver returns Null.i am not sure what is it that i am doing wrong, please help me out.

```
public class GetScreenShot {


    public static String capture(WebDriver driver, String screenshotName) throws Exception
    {
        String dateName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").format(new Date());

        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
        File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        String destination = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/ErrorScreenshots/"+screenshotName+dateName+".png";
        File finalDestination = new File(destination);
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, finalDestination);

        return destination;
    }
}

And here is the code on the Report.

public class ExtentReportsClass{

    //AndroidDriver driver;
    public static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
    public static ExtentReports extent;
    public static ExtentTest logger;
    public static WebDriver driver=null;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void config()
    {
        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/test-output/ABSA_Test_Report.html");
        extent = new ExtentReports();

        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
        extent.setSystemInfo("Host Name", "Software Testing");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "Production");
        extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", "Kgotso Mashabela");

        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Automation Report");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("ABSA Automation Report");
        htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
    }


    @AfterMethod
    public void getResult(ITestResult result) throws Exception
    {
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
        {

            String screenShotPath = GetScreenShot.capture(driver, result.getName());
            logger.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" Test case FAILED due to below issues:", ExtentColor.RED));
            logger.fail(result.getThrowable());
            logger.fail("Snapshot below: " + logger.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShotPath));
            //test.fail("Screenshot below: " + test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(takeScreenShot(result.getMethod().getMethodName())));

        }
        else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            logger.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" Test Case PASSED", ExtentColor.GREEN));
        }
        else
        {
            logger.log(Status.SKIP, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" Test Case SKIPPED", ExtentColor.ORANGE));
            logger.skip(result.getThrowable());
        }

    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown()
    {
        extent.flush();
    }
}
```

And here is my class.

public class IOSClass extends ExtentReportsClass{

```
AppiumDriver driver;
Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();


@BeforeTest
public void OpenSafari() throws MalformedURLException {
    System.out.println("********************");
    System.out.println("Running Safari on IOS...");
    logger = extent.createTest("OpenSafari");

    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Safari");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6");
    capabilities.setCapability("udid", "B7D8F638-F689-4155-BA7F-F7CDD149D75D");


    driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    logger.log(Status.PASS,"Capabilities Configured Successfully ");


}

@Test(priority=1, dataProvider = "MultiBrowser")
public void OpenSafariBrowser(String AppURL,String Ffacebook,String FUsername,String FPassword)throws Exception {

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    SearchFacebook(AppURL,Ffacebook);


    Thread.sleep(5000);
    SignUp(FUsername,FPassword);

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    //Mmessage.PopUpMessage(driver);
    WriteIntoExcel();

}

@DataProvider(name = "MultiBrowser")
public Object[][] provideTestParam(ITestContext context) {
    String ExcelLocation = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("ExcelLocation");
    Object[][] retObjArr =  {{ ExcelLocation }};

    try
    {
        File path = new File("/Users/Documents/Screenshots/TestData.xlsx");
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(path);

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        retObjArr = new Object[sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - 1][4];

        for(int rownum = 0; rownum < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - 1; rownum++){
            Row row = sheet.getRow(rownum + 1);

            retObjArr[rownum][0] = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            retObjArr[rownum][1] = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
            retObjArr[rownum][2] = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
            retObjArr[rownum][3] = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
        }
        file.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return(retObjArr);
}


public void SearchFacebook(String AppURL,String Ffacebook) throws InterruptedException{

    logger = extent.createTest("SearchFacebook");
    System.out.println("Search for Facebook...");

    driver.navigate().to(AppURL);
   // logger.log(Status.PASS,"Browser Launched Successfully ");
    //logger.log(Status.PASS,"The Current URL of the Web page is : "+AppURL);
    String strPageTitle = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("Page tittle "+strPageTitle);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Assert.assertTrue(0 > 1);
   // CaptureScreenShort.captureScreenShot(driver);

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    data.put("1", new Object[] {1d, "Test Description", "Test Step","Screenshots"});

    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(Ffacebook);
    data.put("2", new Object[] {1d, "User entered " + Ffacebook +" to Search", "Field Validation: Text Entered Successfully"});
   // CaptureScreenShort.captureScreenShot(driver);

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#tsbb")).click();
    data.put("3", new Object[] {1d, "User Clicked Button to Search", "Button Validation: Button clicked Successfully"});
   // CaptureScreenShort.captureScreenShot(driver);

    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Facebook")).click();
    data.put("4", new Object[] {1d, "User Facebook Link to Open", "Link Validation: Link clicked Successfully"});
   // CaptureScreenShort.captureScreenShot(driver);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Assert.assertTrue(0 > 1);
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    String title = driver.getTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals("facebook - Google Search1", title);

    System.out.println("Successfully opened Facebook");
    System.out.println("********************");

}
```

See the logs below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.helloworld.GetScreenShot.capture(GetScreenShot.java:20)
    at com.example.helloworld.ExtentReportsClass.getResult(ExtentReportsClass.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:703)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @DebanjanB i would like to say its not duplicate, my program its not taking the screenshot and thats why its returning NulPointerException wheni run it on emulators but if i run it on my PC chrome, its taking the screenshots

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `driver` field from `IOSClass` will make your case work

Comment: Thank you very much. now it is taking the screenshot